# Where can I find galaxy spectra (in the form of FITS files)?

Tags: galaxy, astrophysics, universe, space, spectra

I know there's SDSS and I tried searching for the spectra through the navigate and explore tool under CAS as well as by using RA/Dec coordinates under SAS, but every single time it comes out with 0 results, not part of the database or out of the SDSS threshold.

Moreover, I do not know where I could cross-reference to get the SDSS object id based on other common identifiers (such as NGC) in order to refine my search since I have been solely using RA/Dec coord. as of now.

Any kind of help on how to look for (interactive) spectra would be greatly appreciated. I wanted to use this to calculate the recessional velocities (and rotational velocities by observing H-alpha emission) of different galaxies.

Comment: Have you tried cheking out simbad ? http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/

Comment: I did but simbad doesn't have spectra though? or at least in the form of fits?

Comment: Related question here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32356/where-can-i-find-a-database-of-galactic-spectra?rq=1